# How to search row by 2 columns

Tags: python, database, dataframe

I have been trying for day's to search row in data by 2 inputs I manage to find row by any 1 data that i type

For example if I have list of people who live in United state and their job and i have "bob" "thebuilder" then I want to search up "bob" "thebuilder" and I get the full row of bob job and state, for now what I got I can only type one indicator like "Bob" or "thebuilder" and look up from all the rows that got printed,

That's what I got

```
def searchByName():
name=input('Insert name:')
csv_file=csv.reader(open('names.csv', encoding="utf8"))

for row in csv_file:
    if name==row[3]:
        print(row)
```

and I tried to do it like this

```
enter cdef searchByName():
fname=input('Insert name:')
lname=input('enter last name:')
csv_file=csv.reader(open('names.csv', encoding="utf8"))


for row in csv_file:
    if fname==row[3] + lname==row[4]:
        print(row)
```

when run like this i get no print its loading but get

Process finished with exit code 0

in csv file i got the first names in row 3 and last name at row 4,

What am I missing? search it up all google even tried for hours maybe to combining it on Excel but file to big.

How can I manage to look up that exact row? I want just instead by 1 input from 2, thank you!

Comment: you said "in csv file i got the first names in row 3 and last name at row 4", did you mean columns 3 and for, or were you correct in row 3 and row 4? if thats the case thats why your code isnt finding them, your iterating through the rows, so when you put `fname==row[3] + lname==row[4]`, your getting column 3 and column 4 for that row

Answer (score 0):

you can filter for where a DataFrames columns hold specific values by putting those conditions into square brackets after the DataFrames name, like you slicing a list

```
enter cdef searchByName():
fname=input('Insert name:')
lname=input('enter last name:')
csv_file=csv.reader(open('names.csv', encoding="utf8"))

#assuming your columns names are 0,1,2,3,4....
print(csv_file[(csv_file[3] == fname) & (csv_file[4] == lname)])
```

Comment: Hey thank you for you replay! I tried this as well and got error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/findpeople.py", line 20, in <module>
    searchByName()
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/findpeople.py", line 9, in searchByName
    print(csv_file[(csv_file[3] == fname) & (csv_file[4] == lname)])
TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable

My columns name are first_name and last_name but i saw i need you number to locate the columm i want, as i said with 1 input search i get the result i want but i want to spesific it to 2 inputs

Comment: my mistake! I for some reason thought you were using a pandas Dataframe. this solution should work if instead of `csv_file=csv.reader(open('names.csv', encoding="utf8"))` you were to use `csv_file=pandas.read_csv('names.csv')`

Comment: Nope sir still get Error `raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 3`
In this form its work great but i just want to add another search option from another colum to filter the search for that
`def searchByName():
    fname=input('Insert name:')
    csv_file=csv.reader(open('names.csv', encoding="utf8"))


    for row in csv_file:
        if fname==row[0]:
            print(row)`

How can i add another Input to this code? i'm so sick of tired im 48 hours non stop looking for an answer where im wrong

Comment: where I have `csv_file[3] == fname` you should have `csv_file[column name] == fname` and that should take care of the Keyerror.

  to add another filter you  can add the next in the same way I have mine, within the square brackets, add `& csv_file[other filtered column] == new_filter_variable`. if you need it to print the value of a specific  column with these filters, it would look like `print(csv_file[printing_column][(condition1) & (condition2) & (condition3)]

Comment: Tried this as well i get error `    print(csv_file[(csv_file[first_name] == fname) & (csv_file[last_name] == lname)])
NameError: name 'first_name' is not defined`

Comment: Tried like this `fname=input('Insert name:')
lname=input('enter last name:')
csv_file=csv.reader(open('names.csv', encoding="utf8"))

print(csv_file[(csv_file[first_name] == fname) & (csv_file[last_name] == lname)])
` where im wrong now? i can't just add the filter option to my orignal code? cause i'm trying to figure what you offered me and i just don't get it thank you so much again

Comment: in advance, sorry my code is giving you so many issues, Im pretty new at this haha. the square brackets for pandas Dataframes work similiarly to slicing a list or tuple, with `csv.reader` you get a  '_csv.reader' object that doesnt support slicing, so thats why my filter(ish) code doesnt work for it